# What's the best way to develop a library using composer?

Tags: php, git, composer-php

We're starting a new project, and we're managing dependencies with Composer. We'll probably build our app on top of Laravel 4. But we'll also create our own library, which we will use for all our next projects, not just this one.

So, we have this terrible doubt: what's the best way to develop a library using composer?

If we list that new library as a dependency, every time we modify it we will have to commit the change to the repository and then call `composer update`.

That seems terrible!

Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: Using an SVN, for example, You can set in Your `library` or `vendor` folder, that the concrete library (Your dependency) is updated when You update Your project (external SVN dependency). So the library is updated everytime You run update on the project and You do not need the composer. The very same could be achieved when using GIT. Composer is nice, but I found it like an overkill in many situations (it is nice for first install and setup but then it is almost useless).

Comment: @DenisLins "every time we modify it we will have to commit the change to the repository and then call composer update" That is how I do it, considering the library should be independent. The only difference to any other dependencies is that it is being developed alongside the main project.

Comment: @AlexP the library will be independent, but this workflow sounds too complicated to me... How big is your team? This workflow works for you?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think there are two ways to handle this, which I use depending on the case:

- The library is a pure library, which is standalone, fully tested, and develop it using TDD to ensure that it all works. That way it can be used with the "commit, update" cycle you described just fine I think.
- You are developing a plugin or something that must be integrated in something else (application/framework) and testing it standalone is more difficult, or you are developing it very tightly with your application. In this case require the dev-master version of the library so Composer installs it with a git clone (if it was already installed as a tag you will have to `rm -rf vendor/your/library` to force a reinstall as opposed to an update). You can also force this for tagged releases using the `--prefer-source` flag. Then once you have a clone in the vendor dir you can very easily work directly in there. If you do work in a team though you will still need to do this commit and then update to make sure the others get the latest version.

The third alternative is to just develop the code in the src/ directory of your application until it is mostly stabilized and then you can extract it as a new package and add it back as a dependency, then fall back on the first two ways I described because it will then be a lot more viable.

Comment: The second option seems more viable, which I think was kind of @deceze said as well. I'll try that. Thanks.

Comment: So, I tried that option. The package installed OK, but composer didnt't clone the repo. I flagged the package as dev-master. What am I doing wrong? My composer.json file is here: http://pastebin.com/zs79Fg36

Comment: Your line 31 is the issue, the `preferred-install: dist` means it will always use zip downloads when available. If you remove it it should work.

Comment: Changing "dist" to "source" worked perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the dependency to the repository master branch instead of a packaged distribution file, Composer will check out a working copy into the vendors folder. You can modify this working copy right in the vendors folder, as if it's part of the main project, but then commit it into its own repository. You'll indeed have to make sure to `composer update` after that to keep the `composer.lock` file in sync with the development of that library though.

It's still the more convenient way to develop a project in tandem with a dependency.

Comment: That seems nice, how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you aim to develop a truly awesome library, then you should try to develop it independently of any other software you create.

It should fulfill one exact task only. And this probably is done after some commits, so the initial creation of the library should take only a week or two to come to a stable first version. And this version can be tagged and then used elsewhere.

When tagging, strictly try to follow [semantic versioning](http://semver.org) - that way you can use the library with a version restriction like "~1.0", meaning at least version 1.0, but anything up to 1.9999 is acceptable, as long as it is not 2.0 (which would mean incompatible changes).

And then you really do not need to update any other software when you release a new version of the library. You only need to update if you want to include fixed bugs. Without bugfixes, you *can* update, but there is no need to do so immediately after the library's new version release.

Composer will take care of all the dependencies you need. The most important thing if you start a new library is to include the `composer.json` right from the start into the repository.

What if you really want to always include the newest release of the library in every other software you write? I'm not sure you realize the implications this has. It means that you are strictly binding your other software to the most recent library version. Break that version, or introduce a nasty bug, and all your software breaks. So being able to update or not actually is a feature. You will find that all foreign libraries you might use will follow the same release mechanism: They tag a new version if an important bug was fixed, or if a reasonable amount of new features was implemented. They do not wait for you to approve a new version - you have to approve THEIR new version in your software by explicitly updating to the most recent one. And the same should apply to an internal library.

Try to avoid fiddling with "dev-master" solutions mentioned here. They might work, but Composer works best if used with tagged versions. If you have a reasonably stable state of your library, tag it with "0.0.0" and include that version everywhere else instead of "dev-master". And then tag according to semantic version rules.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, and your thoughts are really valid ones. But I think that the dev-master solution will work better for me, because I'm not building a totally independent library. I'm building a library on top of Laravel, which will contain some common code between our applications. When this library reaches stable, we will possibly start doing this way. Thanks for your help.